# Dynamicly select datasource for entities runtime

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, weblogic, jdeveloper

I have an entity bean that will represent an expected result over multiple databases/datasources and can also be different queries executed, but same result always comming back. So the bean is re-used over different datasources that should be able to be dynamicly selected.

Is it possible with JPA to select during runtime the data source to be used to execute a query, and return the same type of entity bean? 
Also, does my ejb/application need to define the datasources that will be used? Or can I always specify via jndi what datasource to use? Modifying the descriptor's and re-deploying an application everytime a new datasource is created is not an option.

Sorry if the question does not make 100% sense, rather difficult to get the idea through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible with JPA to select during runtime the data source to be used to execute a query, and return the same type of entity bean?

You can't change the datasource of a persistence unit at runtime. However, you can configure several persistence unit and use one or another `EntityManagerFactory`. Maybe JPA is not the right tool for your use case.

> Modifying the descriptor's and re-deploying an application everytime a new datasource is created is not an option.

And how will the application be aware of the "available datasources"?

Comment: Thank you, you are right, JPA will not be the right tool here. I was hoping that's not the case.
With the second question I meant that the j2ee container would have all the datasources configured, but the application itself would not. But that wont matter much if I move away from JPA. 

Thank you.

Comment: That's incorrect. You can modify the datasource of a persistence-unit at runtime. Once modified, any further created `EntityManagerFactory` will have the new datasource. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21157691/698168) on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the JPA datasource at runtime, but the approach is tricky (introspection, JPA implementation specific, ...).

I've implemented my own implementation of `javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`which override the `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` and sets the datasource in both the `Map` and `PersistenceUnitInfo` of the `PersistenceProvider` just before creating the `EntityManagerFactory`. This way, my `EntityManagerFactory` has a datasource which has been configured at runtime. I keep my `EntityManagerFactory` until the application is undeployed.

You could use the same be approach and create N different `EntityManagerFactory`, each with its specific datasource. However keep in mind that each `ÈntityManagerFactory` uses a lot of memory.